# Hypothesis Question and Confidence interval

Tags: probability, statistics

**In 1970, 59% of college freshmen thought that there should be capital punishment , in 2005 a random sample of 100 freshmen were asked whether there should be capital punichment or not, among these, 35 of them said no.**

**Question 1). 
Is there a significant change in the opinion of students in 2005 since 1970.**

The problem that I have for question 1 is that I don't know what fractions to use for the SD. I don't know if it should be $\sqrt{0.59\cdot\ 0.61}$ or $\sqrt{0.35\cdot\ 0.65}$  in these type of problem how do I know which percentage to multiply ?

**Question 2).
Construct a 95% confidence interval for the proportion of all college freshmen who are against capital punishment in 2005.**

For question 2 I have similar issue with picking the correct percentage, I'm not sure if SE =$\sqrt{\frac{0.35\cdot\ 0.65}{100}}$ or SE= $\sqrt{\frac{0.59\cdot\ 0.61}{100}}$ ?

Any advice? Thank you!

Comment: Hint: take as $p$ the expected result.

Comment: @SeanRoberson for hypothesis testing for proportion, do we always use $\sqrt {(proportion of population ) \cdot\ (1- Proportion of population )}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $$H_0:p=0.59$$

$$H_a:p\neq0.59$$

Under the null hypothesis we have that

$$\frac{\hat{p}-p}{\sqrt{\frac{p(1-p)}{n}}}\sim\mathsf N(0,1)$$

When building confidence intervals we have that a $100(1-\alpha)$% confidence interval for $p$ is given by

$$\left(\hat{p}-z_{\alpha/2}\sqrt{\frac{\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})}{n}},\hat{p}+z_{\alpha/2}\sqrt{\frac{\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})}{n}}\right)$$

where in our case $z_{\alpha/2}\approx1.96$

Comment: so in confidence interval we always use Sample proportion to get the SE?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: And when hypothesis testing, we use the population proportion.

Comment: ah ok, thank you for the help. Guess I need to get more familiar with the formula. My text book doesn't list any of the formulas